# Adding properties to a Control in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to add some properties to some of the Controls inside the .NET framework.
For example, I want to add a list of related controls - not the containing controls that already exists - to make some sort of link controls.

What I did is create a small interface decorator, implemented by a concrete decorator that extends from the class Control. Here I put the new properties and the methods to manage them.

The main problem is that when I create an instance of my decorated Control, I must pass as a parameter an instance of the base Control - let's say, Combobox -, and it is referenced in one of those new properties inside the decorator class.

When I try to paint that component, I'm unable to. And also not sure about why. The Control just doesn't show up.

Here is the decorator code:

```
    public class ControlDecorator : Control, IDecorator
    {
    private List<Control> RelatedControls = new List<Control>();
    private Control Control;

    public ControlDecorator(Control c)
    {
        this.Control = c;
        this.Control.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseClick);
    }
```

And here is how I create the Controls:

```
    Control lb = new Label();
    lb = new ControlDecorator(lb);
    editableArea.Controls.Add(lb);
    editableArea.Refresh();
```

Comment: BTW - terrible naming of the field.

Comment: "Decorator" sounds like using the Decorator pattern of the GOTF, but it's not implemented properly (should not use inheritance but holds a reference to the decorated object)

Answer (score 1):

did you override the OnPaint method ??  as you have to Over-ride the method. you can change your field name to some descriptive name, rather than making ambiguous with Control Class. 
[OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx)

[Control Class documentaiotn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36cd312w.aspx)

[Over riding on paint method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce.aspx)

Comment: I was thinking that the problem could be there. I suposse that I could override it and tell him to paint the Control - terrible named - field, but I have no idea on how to do it and searching didn't help.

Comment: @Ed. check this link, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to call InitializeComponent() method in ControlDecorator constructor.

```
public ControlDecorator(Control c)
{ 
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Control = c;
  this.Control.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseClick);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public ControlDecorator(Control c)
{
    this.Control = c;
    this.Controls.Add(c);
    this.Control.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseClick);
}
```